# 404 - Unique 404 page not found

Tags: code-golf, polyglot, rosetta-stone

Inspired by [a polyglot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27846/344102) <s>on the [Stack Overflow 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/error-404)</s>:

[image]

## Goal

Your goal is simple, to create a polyglot that outputs the number **404**, and then terminate, in as many languages as possible.

## Restrictions

Here's the twist, there's a restriction to make it harder:

You have to write **N** programs and pick **N** languages in a particular order. the **i**th program needs to print `404` in the first **i** languages, but not in any language after the **i**th. This is to prevent very simple solutions from destroying competition

## Scoring:

- The first criterion for determining a winner is the number of languages the main program runs in.
- The second criterion is byte count, where the programs with more languages have more importance for this criterion.
- The third and final criterion is time of submission

## Clarifications:

The source codes of the programs do not need to have any relation. They're run as separate programs. Any of the programs can output trailing and/or leading whitespace. **THE PROGRAMS DO NOT HAVE TO BE SUBSEQUENCES OF EACH OTHER!**

Thanks to @MartinEnder for a better explanation!

Comment: Can the sub program be inserted into the previous or only appended? For example 1) ><> `# ;nnn404` 2) ><> and Befunge-93 `#  ]404,,,@;nnn404`

Comment: The source code of the subprograms do not need to have any relation. They're run as separate programs

Comment: Bytecount of the final program or the total of every program?

Comment: So "Working" is outputting and "Not Working" is doing anything else?

Comment: @JoKing, I just edited that.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Yes, working is outputting 404. It's edited now

Comment: Is it okay if we output with a leading newline?

Comment: You think anyone is going to get to 404 languages?

Comment: @JoKing That would be greater than the current "add a language to a polyglot" challenges, so probably not...

Comment: "The source code of the subprograms does not need to have any relation" - but they must each be a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of the full (byte-count) program that runs in all N languages, right? If not could you please define "sub-program"?

Comment: "submission" means the post, not the code. Thanks for bringing that up

Comment: I evidently suck at explaining things

Comment: I think I fixed it now,

Comment: @Zacharý Maybe don't talk about subprograms. Just say something like "you have to write **N** programs and pick **N** languages in a particular order. the **i**th program needs to print `404` in the first **i** languages, but not in any language after the **i**th".

Comment: To be clear, if a program prints 404 but also errors it is considered working, right? Also is any leading or trailing whitespace allowed? By the way I think this is a great challenge

Comment: +1 only because now I know what that crap was. I just ignored it before. Oh no, this cannot be unseen now!

Comment: Are programs ending in infinite loops allowed?

Comment: What do you mean, @JoKing? You mean output 404 then go into an infinite loop? I'd have to say no there

Comment: @Zacharý why's that? They print 404. If trailing whitespace is OK I think that should be OK.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## 54 Languages, 1331 bytes

[><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish),
[Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish),
[Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo),
[Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93),
[Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI),
[brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck),
[Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack),
[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),
[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),
[Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony),
[Perl](https://www.perl.org/),
[Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/),
[Julia](http://julialang.org/),
[Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal),
[Brainbash](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brainbash),
[Turtlèd](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Turtl-d),
[Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-),
[Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php),
[Braille](https://gist.github.com/threeifbywhiskey/0e98d42150eb644a3406),
[Rail](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail),
[Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission),
[ETA](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tech/eta/doc/),
[Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html),
[Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/),
[Numberwang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Numberwang_(brainfuck_derivative)),
[Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously),
[Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji),
[Symbolic Brainfuck](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf),
[TinCan](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tincan),
[Alphuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck),
[Shove](https://github.com/TryItOnline/shove),
[Cood](https://github.com/jesobreira/cood/tree/php-interpreter),
[Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise),
[Width](https://github.com/stestoltz/Width),
[Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers),
[Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue),
[Surface](https://github.com/TryItOnline/surface),
[Stones](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones),
[evil](https://web.archive.org/web/20070103000858/www1.pacific.edu/%7Etwrensch/evil/index.html),
[Set](https://github.com/somebody1234/Set),
[Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude),
[Gaot++](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus),
[Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix),
[Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically),
[PATH](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pathlang/),
[Commercial](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/commercial),
[Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck),
[Monkeys](https://github.com/TryItOnline/monkeys),
[Nhohnhehr](https://github.com/catseye/Nhohnhehr),
[Beam](https://github.com/ETHproductions/beam-js),
[AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots),
[Alumin](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Alumin),
[Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice),
[Whirl](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Whirl/)

This is getting very long, so at @MDXF's suggestion, I'm moving the subprograms and comments to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/GrayJoKing/60ab9a603791381171c091bcc3eec189). The program here is only the final program. Thanks to MDXF again for providing the TIO test driver.

## 54. [Whirl](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Whirl/)

````
##\$"404"#N#S# , ,,#$#?@\404!?@GJlICJlGCC*G^+0%=%=+0%x&fqpqqqiipsoddddoiipsohphhhhyhhhh? 	  ?nnn4$4#!000110000011110000100000100000110000011001100000111100001110011000111000110000
#?\++++:----:++++:H@((((4O0O4O@((((()()()){}){x}x){}x()){}){}()){}){})<[-]>[-]-[<+>-----]<+x%"404"?.⌂----.++++.>11     
#i(N/"404"ooo@ENTHOEONHSSEONTHOEONSETssipceaiiiiiscejiiiijeeeejapmzaeeaeueewzaeeeaeewzaeeaeueewqs??|?)999|997+|++++!999777+++++!999997+++++!   	  
print(404)	
 		
 		
 	
__DATA__=1
# \"404"*CC'[-][ .-$_"404"&]
"""pp
I want 404 of this
How much is it
#  -52, Z, -1                          #
#  -48, Y, -1                          #
#  -52, X, -1                          #
[-][
x::=~404
::=
x
]<<<
> 404
>> Output 1
red up two blue up red up one blue up red up two blue up
baaaaa bleeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeet baaaaa bleeeeeeeeet
a now 404 dollar off!
a has been selling out worldwide!
2 LEFT
2 LEFT
2 UP
2 LEFT
2 TEACH
1 LEFT
1 RIGHT
1 BOND
1 BOND
1 TEACH
2 YELL
1 FIGHT
2 YELL
1 TEACH
2 YELL
set ! 52
set ! 48
set ! 52
+------+
|$0011\|
|/000\0|
|0/0@11|
|00  10|
|0\10/0|
|\1100/|
+------+
$'main'
 \-444o000o444omm^

[-][$++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.----.++++.#
<<<<<<```>>>>.>.>.
]
ss"""
#7777777777777777777777777777724091557093543643404➡77▲▲▲²²▲²²¡▼▼▼▼¡▲▲▲▲¡⠎⡆⡎⡆⢐⠣⠃s&&&&~-<<:<<:<<<:<:>>>>>>>>:^||||G<>
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVfdUuPIFb6efoqDbTCskWUbMwxgm7HBA7M7BVMLSXaDGY9@2laDpBZqCezFTCWbqr1KpVJJ1V5mh@Q2V3udq73OU7AvkDcgp1v@gbFhU2lZfb5z@lPr9FGf7rZpCOfuzjIiqFncpvmoFxGShm19O5cjXcsCrQcWjJpA42DleRxBqabb9EL3Y9cl3VxO0VA8IAbBFBW7bno8Yj73mMV9QnsBDyPYP9hptt/Wj/aqKT0Woe4yU/exq7bH7dilIiUfrIdWn8fE9UHrCNB5EOmGMumeETl5xJL1hrl9YgUTTxRwpRVbD/ueyV1mQSM0mN@JrTPicZ8nvQmzI@887dHJ47WFknzwC4378EryVazgrJMPXKhUKqlMUXrXoJ3Y71JtfSVxEPJJD4xPUN7sENLhIfSA@dAiqaAfOdxfSd7eYcJRVT7oj1@fmqJ1uauYIrRGeOqBpD/O5T2jxUx81U3mS/w4Q1t/oUgd02SzWKMYTtBjLMdAlor5nvEpKxneJOLpt8pQAptT4WcjcNkZhdhnkvEgIA@6CWOzn4TIoT2jy/2@zvyIhkFIsc6H5idvpaErv9N0H9NDOI1dZjxXoVDwic9jGaHNfMMdg9kfRwXFxNyboIesNLPPwOGXEHHA@WjFEYWjOIxcaiviMpiYWkxAREVE7WlHbGrYcnJoYzTbk0uHYReBYVH9UolHvHVdOpIzGLJBVbMmIhOCcX8kZzBoZMh7RksUsm6XhiM5gyE8mbVYPWw7NS4M0HAdUCQ/9kwaXhp@F/Yn8PGvaFhRbLhuH7NMTE2SxGWPn7Kknorr7BVFWXE1SZaDB2tMep9HIOKQjr64zSFymLgXB@Zbhj8UT6ai4QbO7EQUDr@gST01psAZRsri3H6QN7JlVromk4cJqqqn16xLZkdOUv8CEQeNiSnGYPacjZw4Wb0kmDXSOOzICT2UsxgR96nQIyPsUpy91KUGjiSxzpxIriEwOyIn8ZNe4ExX1eNjEVTdjww44WCM3dimI/kkt2vwKAiUaAduLFQln9C0DpuZlFZssl5S35trR5MFY8yy1GQfI@jEs/woDZ3GMKjtR8XjcZ7FPY@GFpOL4RhODXGybJshM3zNcpINZYynVm5Fxmw6o30xkk@44Tvc8R3qhMrnsfbIukwNT/EkuBe03/DwTMxYJ4TFmM0jobfbHmZgu/3E@Aw39nDOJmJqVPd5DOfuU3vXKFdCN6kftBKbEwBI9rft@iFoTcjGAnfQqPNik3UWM/Uvd399XDipfgBPp//@nb50FYT4ug6k5rW15yK1DCPK5jV1Bb3fvIrNk9YspDK9lHwdbosew2PfIZ73pJ7pwQCiEDQbstDyW2EryqLFwb0IswmKqwXUEh/dAB30qpMTFLyejF3foWaslv6LUr60UgXDtyHTrlZqCoXU5psg9ON3rV6poLV6a80TXYz8bbV684XSVzggHuJTC3qXbkJzf@cqk68VBgNh9CGVus5ixHx6d5dOtzKpcqGcSu@nD9OwDMvL6Ux662ULbXNbL3c/d19vf@7ubm9/tvsuV5ivzlex7i10zoPz83PGAsFtLFwhJ3Cw9GW1Bc8AtnzfL2fK6blCoVAsFgpKJGCoDW1j8SlrbCsOa2kl6a1WDsuGhmVDob2Xi1jKB4WD8oGCi0vyWrq6XrrqXfdQ9oba9UguVY61kxre2nElV5NdaSeVXG9eBWMrf/vHb6UpL7vP14pFkIWk2eK@rhic85fN/aO9g@bB/t7hIdYJPmwe4YYfWNRgsgiLnkp5SrGcGoH3jUGpQWNKLyVCmIDEdC62tgZbS@vr64P19bXcQL58DrW1tbXcCMsGhdEfjDFRn30RXVp6RuDZ6Cbt9k79qN5uV4t4jm8plz/b3s7ieI8hr2XayrJwQlKpVBCQ14BngwjQBryjdmGyh5uyF1uOPG6xCDsBbbW0DL9dBi0JxsySVsTyi2X4@n8hyh6/@iWi9Jn0NjaqH9A/gpL0yAn@CSE16TCp1eAgjgI8GBYJZgbEAUSXHEwXd0nEQxNO9k9N91jENGRBlY5K9IkyTSAG@BgkGTSbu64RYuw6c2h1DAEmpT4I6roMz1zyD@ElD10bTwN0jpTgTfPV0UT86u0EHzXr23ukmKhF@PL17p6UjYP9nYlISCX4uvnmDaqvFGmsPmjFzRjmYLU0BOUXE0tOTXotRwYZmVqtARnomF6tAoKCXnhZLEpQACgqS6uIRgQtmYX6YPJ4Jit3gSyBllYulzl2waX0vHdEfbtM7v8o@Un2pUlFlffv39ew5OVFTogQOHdJeu2pUioX1ourq2uF9ZXV8srz8sp/fvjLP/GDSXH7t5u1tdvvf0x@P@E1FD/d3H7/r/FPaj9OaDe3H/90e/Pd7Y2q//7n24//uP34B7GA5YNWqWyoH94btWHZeDfAslup3c1b1fPLxXq9Dpkgl4N6vYFA06DeqMOONDQasIN6Q@oL1dLq6iZudC5d3Fm6QmNjZLyGBvah8j5nOeEOqthWxdV@Ec911tLSJsno1czyptoxNnGfqDdOdL2L6Offf/fzt3/V60PlB6k0lHL8bkzK5/N6xrrKLFxvSv145ySbMY8zwUm2u0kvDPe/)

Whirl is described as a Turning Tarpit [sic], which uses only two instructions, 1 and 0. 1 rotates the current wheel of instructions (either the math wheel or the operations wheel), 0 swaps the rotation of the wheel, and two 0s executes the instruction and switches wheels. The relevant instructions are on the first line:

`000110000011110000100000100000110000011001100000111100001110011000111000110000`

```
000110000 Switch to math wheel and execute math.not (math.val = 1)
011110000 Execute math.store, (memval = math.val = 1)
10000     Execute math.add, (math.val = math.val+memval = 1+1 = 2)
010000    Execute math.store (memval = math.val = 2)
0110000   Execute math.multiply, (math.val = math.val*memval = 2*2 = 4)
01100     Execute math.store (memval=math.val) and switch to the ops ring
110000    Execute ops.one (ops.val = 1)
011110000 Executes ops.intio, printing memval (4)
11100     Add one to memory pointer (memval=0)
1100      Execute maths.nop to switch back to ops ring
011100    Execute ops.intio, printing memval (0)
01100     Execute maths.store, (memval=maths.val=4)
00        Execute maths.intio, printing memval (4)
```

The leading 01s cancel each other out, and the trailing 01s cause a floating point exception.

Edit: fixed a *bunch* of broken stuff

(Commands to be careful about in the future: `UDLR%"[.]o473psjw`)

If any programs work for future languages or don't work for current or previous languages, please comment.

Comment: @Zacharý RE: my comment under the OP - at some stages this has `...print(0 or 404)` but it is not a subsequence of the 97 byte N-program.

Comment: @JonathanAllan yeah, I was a little concerned about that too. Sub-program *does* imply they are related to the final program, but I’m going off the question specs here

Comment: No, you're not going off question specs. "Submission" meant the entire post, not the code.

Comment: I think I fixed the specs now

Comment: Hey it won't work in brain-flak, # is comment

Comment: Oh brain-hack :P

Comment: You should be able to add Actually if you can stick `.` after the `"404"` and then `⌂` before any other `.`s.

Comment: @Mego Done. Was a little harder than suggested, but it all worked out

Comment: I think you should be able to add [TinCan](https://tio.run/##K8nMS07M@/9fWUFB19RIRyFKR0HXUAEnUOYCKTSx0FGIJEYhyMQIAgr//wcA). @MDXF too. I can't because Jelly and M won't allow any line to begin with `#`. I'm really regretting including those two languages haha.

Comment: 35, wow this got ridiculous fast

Comment: If you can add [#hell](http://esolangs.org/wiki/HashHell) with two characters mad props

Comment: Turning Tarpit ... LOLOL

Comment: The `[sic]` isn't needed actually; it is in fact a Turning Tarpit, not just a misspelling of Turing Tarpit. [It's a type of Turing Tarpit that uses a wheel of instructions.](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Turning_tarpit)

Comment: @Makonede I'm pretty sure I knew that, I was just using `[sic]` in an unconventional way to signal that I wasn't making a typo myself

Answer (score 20):

## 53 languages, 2789 bytes

Bash, Foo, Implicit, Charcoal, Emoji, ><>, rk, Brain-Flak, C, Set, Cood, Arcyou, TRANSCRIPT, S.I.L.O.S, Commercial, C++, Braille, Deadfish~, Memescript 1.0, ETA, Python 1, Python 3, PARI/GP, Lily, Fission, Decimal, Cubically, Bitwise, TinCan, Whispers, Thue, Emotinomicon, what??!, Ook!, evil, Lennyfuck, Blablafuck, Stones, TacO, COW, Symbolic Brainfuck, Underload, Rail, Reticular, Gaot++, PATH, axo, Monkeys, Nhohnhehr, xEec, VTFF, K-on Fuck, Churro, and Forked. 
Try everything online in the [test driver!](https://tio.run/##rRjbbtvI9Z1v7RccybItWeZFitxkLUuuFDnrpIm1iJ1ttpYTUORIZExxGF4sqbIW3QYIij5si16CbVE0cYstUHRbFHlt0Yc8Ft2PqPIB3T9Izwx1MSXGyQY7Is99zpwZnjkcqql6xqtXmupDWaM6kfyeLwhLcFW@ms0KbU0DsQcaTFQgUtAkGviQL8s6OZHtwLKEdjbLzRBFDB1nwRRd73Sob9q0Y2rUFkjPoa4Pe/Xazv0PKge7paQceK5smU3ZRlf3O1QPLOIlWceKq/VpIFg2iC0PZOr4sspFckf1DQlpZnXTtPqC5swi4YTFpKjd73ea1DI1qLqqabcC7VjoUJuG3rxmi90S6ZFZ9/JKnnX8nkhtuMbs@VrBcUtyLNja2kqmchhdi7rQA9OGhpBs4pJO@yeZhHtvUcruGI1ndhycpK9qx@dpaAUxxpqBE6WqNSUkpx9jRjr0gRnCBQOn7xvUvhROumV6BgfxftxjvKJyN2j2w75Ntohiy1KPQ/I@IyW3GbWXZJ4yi0N7hN@L8RlOaKBRqsum7RPXcQlCiWleP5VxNiBadElcKzTyXdX2NNeMkOxZRuwfqCcqiJqlep6DyTWO17SoB/scxkSRnwTd6RBXM9kjmpILAeGihNtjttRsCS2LTPAFE9WJqrNHJk6pBf@bcIt0SDg7MD2wKSIb8wo964C5fHC9fi5bfJXdMc8/HDc3xvExxfRSXVNsO3LbAfFh3F4wPc@k9gTHWOhEMzu4hMp7tbhNEDRNDafSn1Hxu6Vp@l3TIxMcY4G1SFPtMbpgzbuG6WEWeVMifr/4RsBGszkR1bOCBpPNOS2BEUZ64M0/xu8bqr@9nbjwGW5CnR5fbBKb0OTEtICDuUFvEtvus@r4hmGrltq01DcahrvHpzbxZF9127jvXWIRFR9MKI2ObwXqeK@qGsXibtoSE8WkAe2yO6rh9ZxLsI6P47xj61gAqKqzMLvEdBfDY5uOg9cVO6xAphZYqjujFkrdeJdw@7ZKfcfh6L5jBR4HLGlEsWXGb@9xBWEPSPZcjRMx08YZHpO@N8EXeLINatgGMVzubsrFp26PEE3u7RBtPhs@PLh27cLny6vr@I041/eqEbguvai3oFMBALgP8WplH8QdWA1wrwZ@60rRbKVTldvvf3ioHJU@ho5M/vMjOTNwXHwrtCC5LF7@jpdch4lJcUgsj5xXb6B6pl2FZKqXZMMFltkx8Ziyj@cTxqd6cAq@C6IOq9CwG27DX0WJgfUVtw3kNhTkwhgtBwPslKqkFdhtIr53Ca7PXlFyjTSDdpu4cJKX8pdKoNo6pO6XtsqccolOi@DJh/cavbwiNnqXd45kbxJvo9FbVvJ3cUIUMzS1IrdJEXb2aoOUVFZOTz21D8nkcBVXzCavXi0FmNUtsJJQUApJp5jG1sgo4a@Y/urpZ38tIHg@@tkXjFbO0RP5i79g1xf/ONzcWMvlxJycO1peyaRRltm/J6/tYTvY29up7@3u7yM82K0jNE2P6tgoIwxeeCJgewqkGLANiz3eAmxHqTmniSj1tkD6OmDcYxtbYjuBF2JE0ZbgskRIRjUJLkqMFYnRp7/lS//V0198gQRDo9@fgU@BHSV9g/B0oS0mOX/hRpooQY1oVC6M3FC0C7ZiF4SlXA4HqV1ScjBtjcKysuwsrwhJbEQzKEuj01Nwjzdxk7pss/p4pi0xMfAM3UQWtQRd306ynFvD87vpF4WlolC/cwArG3lYyYVk4cqU5FJYk4UlfMdagU62PF83qWSUBVbb05kBO8qCWjk8Kg0uXV7PKcq6MiyGmyKtVtZZPhaH8toWa50fqoQQvFVs3QBbl1HQxfckX5qWa7Kzs8tO0E0EPqc82@SQ0Vi9AV8tERmWWr8PXUbqpq7j5wLo520jwvNDPAxwrYjbnJMLvc3N0scYuYBY6MGSgCddSMBGHldr9OzT0dnj0RmHf/j56NkfR88ejZ48D68X@BujF2ejJ/@cXox7PjM7S49@8zl8@bt/P0GcScOXZy/@nk6PfvJnTnEFpzKjnz4a/eqT0WeP//evp9Jael7931//KZS9fPS3ieTzqO93YDKhq3eIJ13mzNY7DTvrvOD2HQQTZ9@Ka99@CwlrLz95/PLHv4yDT18DX2f5@EKb13n@piQXx/n0a0b7TcVz8Vq9m2ReCwM6LJVKw0EpbMjiNcfOGQhlVjiFchnqge8EPuSE61hfsKayesoKO35HSMIuHl87gWawwm7628KNgFEGcYkklG8E66GTu3AjEJphLRZ4YcQjBzShOK4qWG1v0Xp4TQsNE9XrtzooyorjlhVOU4qSyykNOBVOZQVbTmZkA2XKWMrJUKogCVw6eW2cYlHlBbdpkUnzmRpDc74bsTw/bGqV1fpV/FLBiOoY2C0MHhpioVCgOBplWBxspVL3RCgPswPe7WSYlRiWstikJWEJIqNOIrk3GXErqi4Lebi5c@1ghu58MKMPdipXd4VcyObg9vX3dxmu1vdqMxQa5eGjnZs3kb3GjaZsRItHOwgc8LsUo8BvP6THIjytzYvOWxUFiofjLs8LnVr4XeFhfrQSKDZUD5qE2OARyzLtNrD/07rUtfSuqZMEWxBxI78OP1gH8dyrfb7xlRMLV9bho7cxZB7vvslw8QXGzp8Om0UGCXYjwF9mMIy5wFjCXbCESAkR5/AkEqY3P4MuJdfkV8ta6WE3XalUIOVks1CpVJEQRahUK1BjgmoVashXGb9Sym9sFPEL3SLpWmaAwupEOIQq@uDOs5rh1pBFXQkP2mn8HtUymaKQkkup9SI/rBfxiF6pHslyG6mwCMiVMcOqg1zlzOG9qZEkSXJKG6RWhkXGH9aOVlPNw5RztNoukhPV@j8)

Join us in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72240/unique-404-page-not-found) for this challenge!

---

This post got way too large so here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaronryank/49d3546428c56de8cde1a59c24d0d5c6) containing my progress. Current final program:

## [Forked](https://github.com/aaronryank/Forked)

```
#undef l" 404"p;((((\)0)0)0)0;(4⏬0⏬4⏬«404»[:5*11-1/1]%&)(404)S^/*NNNNTNNEONHSSEONTHOEONiisoddddoiisohOok! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. ????!?!!?!??!!!???????????????!?!!!?!????!??????????????!!??!??!??!????!⎚404»404➡ to for the and of to to to to to is the and  a to to to to a and and and and a ;n4n0n4
#11404D301          \4%0%p%&
""""echo 404|| rk:start int x = 404 print: x rk:end R"404"*
exit;
#;
OUT &52 &1
OUT &48 &1
OUT &52 &1 */
#include<stdio.h>
main(){char aA[]={37,100,0};printf(aA,404);}/*<<<<<mzaeeeaeeaaaawuuuuwaaaa what the frick frack backtrack snick snack tic tac snick snack patty wack diddily dack tic tac diddily dack frick frack quarterback frick frack
x::=~404
::=
x #
set ! 52
#;⠎⡆⡎⡆⢐⠣⠃▲▲▲²²▲²²¡▼▼▼▼¡▲▲▲▲¡(♥ ͜ʖ♥)( ͡°((∩ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)⊃━☆ﾟ.*( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)ᕦ( ͡°ヮ ͡°)ᕥ(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)) ͡°)(∩ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)⊃━☆ﾟ.*( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)(> ͜ʖ<)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(♥ ͜ʖ♥)(> ͜ʖ<)( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)(> ͜ʖ<)うんうんうんうんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうん {o}===}{======={o}{o}}{======={o}{o}===}{======={o}
> 404
>> Output 1
I want 404 of this.
How much is it?
Ju is here.
>Ju, 404
>X Ju
b = 404
printInt b ;
set ! 48 MoOMoOMoO
set ! 52 MoOOOMmoO
+--------+
|$00110\ |
|/00001/ |
|\11000\ |
|/11000/ |
|\0100 \ |
|        | baaaaa bleeeeeeeeet
|  404p@ |
|        |
+--------+
$'main': OOMmOoOOM ;
 \-444o000o444o-{<$$^- >}+{-----v}+.----.++++.#
#  bleeeeeeeeet baaaaa ^        < bleeeeeeeeet >
2 LEFT
2 LEFT
2 UP
2 LEFT
2 TEACH
1 LEFT
1 RIGHT
1 BOND
1 BOND
1 TEACH
2 YELL
1 FIGHT
2 YELL
1 TEACH
2 YELL
red up two blue up red up one blue up red up two blue up ;
o now 404 dollars off!
o has been selling out worldwide!
#  -52, Z, -1                          #
#  -48, Y, -1                          #
#  -52, X, -1                          #
⡆⡎⡆⢐⠣⠃((((p 404)((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){}) h#4 o# h#0 o# h#4 o# """
print(404)#"*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZtb9tUFP5@v8EvOG7azknzYneumJImoWMdadU2aM2kjWWVnPgGW03t4NikIwnSqFQhPgzESzUQog1oSIiBUL@C@NCPSPsRc38A@wfl3Ou8OX1ZF@34@pznPOf43pOrm2NXLHuTaicnIdfUaAWqE6BIykQtJaIUw5J/pcQX@49/V1Adel88ZVgawj3@6Dd89Oive8m5iCzH5IR8f2o6LCIXXt9IRNZQCmtri/m13Po66kIuj9ow6paGYjGg561NAQIq21fxM1QWTj9xCZUNopFJhSC6rIq/iuo@kUURsgIOtGiCInBO8GEwInBK6AYE79H3fOtf7H/1FAEz3o8dcCyoWDY4OgXV1MCqMGZ4GPV@ENRAROVk4IaUqZiSqZCQLOMiN65KMvSlqExJU7WpaTKBQsu6xY5RqwX2ZrLuqLYDhunANqQZDTUbvSS6GKU49a0JduYihG4bToqEUiR/uwDTc7MwLftQudaHnIVIgoQMs1x1NTpfdzTDiusZsqUaphhulnXVBnXh3v108@pbUVmSolI7xZesiOpClJ3HVDsRmWey9bFKKcVbRWm4KA2GoKGrDt@aim2UN1GrqEuoHI7qpsE1w45RBkctB7ia6jgPoMGgZmiaUX0A2nBugBxe4kMX94rapRGebCeT6U@wcoKWbEOI1KkDAszN4m55B4@8zq7X4fqnL72Dn72DHW/v0B9HeHXNUcfb@7s/mHc4SOuI3ndP4NkP/@6hDYvwrHP0pyh6n/3KEQ9wFPY@3/G@eeg93v3vn/14RBwNP//2F5873vmjxzwJzj2GE/anGqMeMcOd@bGWHTx8atoxiN5kb5wlb16CYXL8cPf406/P0vvn6PMydy/MOW/m18VcXOf@K1b7uuq5eK/GY0aj0LTa6XS63Uz7gi6OEXckgWRY4ySZDORdp@Y6IJMl7C/YU1k/ZY1dN@pxkrMasOWWddbYDSdLll2GdGrTOMksu1F/kjuw7JKS34sJb4xLOFEJUt2ugt121cr7o99oGJXPr24hNRPrygxpTUqSLEtFaJFWQkKREwwWkZO6LIc@KyEEzvZeGy1sqrzhlqq0Jw4LY2m1twOZw8tOXmG9/koSWEV5LGwVi4diTFEUC1ezmI015ycnN2KQac80@WMftWfizMZnUOIhEoLAqr1KNnorzgfDGTILK4s3CwNz@70BLiwuvJMjsu/KcGvp3Ryz1/NrNwbGT5qFu4srK@je5El9NxC1qQZuDZyGhVW4lOEuZZl0lBrOShELTDwG7FxoVrWq2nU8HxUBaV2tQ4lSE@q0WjXMD8DCg9Sw7KrWMDQqsA2Jzc1G4f0oxIZe7aPCdy6mXIvC3cskshnvvCzx9AuMfX/W2K8II2A3KrzCzfYZA/QQ/gtCaCTfcA@/RPzjzb9BQxORxMnJ/w)

My new (-ly implemented) esolang!

Comment: what the frick frack paddy wack (give the dog a bone) is that language? (congratz on passing me)

Comment: @JoKing honestly I have no idea what was going through my head when I made that language.... also thanks for the help with Braille and Deadfish~, I hope you don't mind that I used your code?

Comment: no worries mate

Comment: MDXF v. Dylnan, I see.

Comment: @Zacharý MD XF v Dylnan v Jo King; every time I pull ahead, I fall asleep and then have to go to school and by the time I get back on they both are ahead again, building off my languages and each others'... *sigh*

Comment: this is my last day of work for the week, so you bet i'll be catching up!

Comment: If we get our own site design, the winner definitely goes on the 404.

Comment: @Zacharý will you also accept the winner? (I'm going to try as hard as I can to win and I've never had one of my answers accepted before)

Comment: I will eventually, but when the updating slows down

Comment: @Zacharý yeah wait at least a week

Comment: I didn't see that you'd already done Cood, but you can get rid of the `Hey waiter!` part, and the ending punctuation on the other two lines.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PT/n/X7k0LyU1TaHi0GoTA5NDu1XV9LV0o2207XRBINZGWw9E62kDgd6jvllgNR/mT1oDZICoR/MWWueZ5BnkmXClJmfkKwCFa2oUirKtiksSi0oUCooy80qsFJSAwkpcqRWZJdZa@ly5iZl5GprVyRmJRQqJ0bG21cbmOoYGBjoGtdZg9WkaiTpADZrWtfpaGkCgCcVAAgg1q2uxIK7i1BIFRQVTIyjDxAIh4qlQnphXAnKaQn6aQklGZjGXR365Qm5pcoZCZrFCZgmXlv7//wA "Cood – Try It Online")

Comment: Normal brainfuck no longer works. It prints a bunch of null characters, `4044` and enters an infinite loop (lol can't post TIO link because too long)

Comment: Braille is broken now. I checked because it had been broken on mine since I added Symbolic BF. @JoKing somehow your program works for both Braille and Symbolic BF. Should we start a chat room for this challenge? I don't know how to do it

Comment: @JoKing I can't fix it, I just removed Brainfuck.

Answer (score 13):

## 34 Languages, 387 characters

**[Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),
[M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m),
[Pyon](https://github.com/alexander-liao/pyon),
Proton, Python 3, Python 2, Python 1, Perl 6, Perl 5, Ruby, bc, Pari/GP, brainfuck, Emoji, Emotinmicon, Charcoal, Braingolf, Whitespace, Deadfish~, Deadfish, Self-modifying Brainfuck, Symbolic Brainfuck, Numberwang, Cardinal, Actually, Fission, Prelude, Brain-Flak (BrainHack), Alphuck, Deadfish x, TacO, Braille, 
[rk](https://github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang),
evil**

This answer is getting very long so [here](https://gist.github.com/dylannrees/0036e918153b2c5d5b827f1fcb1a84dc) is the full answer. From now on only the last program will be kept here.

If anyone finds that one of the programs is broken for one language or one program works for a language it shouldn't, let me know.

```
print(404)   	  
+1#<[-]>--[<+>-----]"404".⌂<+.----.++++.404➡⎚404»___pppissiiiisiiiio▲▲▲²²▲²²¡▼▼▼▼¡▲▲▲▲¡sipceaiiiiiscejiiiijeeeejaxxcxxxcxxxKddddKcxxxx7777777724091557093543643%R"404";77999++++++++!++++++++6+1+!++++++5++++!> @p404 sp7 rk:start print: "404"77szaeeaeueewzaeeeaeewzaeeaeueew
   	  
+1#((a(()a((()(((()()())a{})a{})a{})a{})a{})a{})a{})	
 		
 		
 	


+1#ṛ“Nạç»⠎⡆⡎⡆⢐⠣⠃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNSsNAED43T7FWhA2hobVJl9RQvBc8eC2lLHUPqaJLEzUoQlHwJEV6KFLFNnrQg6fetJ7ik3SfoG8QZzeJPfnNfDPf/DCwy868oyThfe84wFbZ0hFCBYQ0o7LptkrtRqnUcg2IgHYR5kVT3F27hikbpgEwV9PRBwxkEs/RavowAg6y/J5TDCewFC86nQ7n3PN9D6DCiRjPU4/BshRHYvz957Kar9ci3@NdRj11ost6MvcYoEfDsBumbB4AmlKFJMO2VXYqtk3KTtW2qjWrurWvnrRDiOM4RoaNXNSMSl7YatBAuxz2kc8J6h/W/YD2A6R@ro7UIUL8C8oYZaeMnUsFMhVpS1t/LsYUYx2IdawCmE4vr/5lQUOFnJomTyw/H8XgaW/5Ff28xQsxG4roVkQqvtyL2auY3STJLw)

Comment: Wow, congrats, you've just blown everyone else out of the water.

Comment: @MDXF Thanks! I'm planning on doing more I just have to stop for now.

Comment: If only the Julia versions were different enough I could've beaten you by 10 bytes with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153772/61563) *sigh*

Comment: @MDXF Someone did post a double Julia answer to the Trick or Treat polyglot question exploiting some bug but it got deleted and I don't remember what it was

Comment: @dynlan well I can see deleted posts so I'll go check it out, thanks!

Comment: Brainbash prints some stuff before the 404. How about [this](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLSizO@P@/oCgzr0TDxMBEk0vbUDlaN1Y32kbbThcEYm209UC0njYQ6H2YP2kNUBmIejRv4Yf5MyYBcQOIftS/CkiteNS/8lHfLKCSQ7vj4@NBpj3cOftRwxy/h7sWHl5@aPf//wA)?

Comment: @JoKing which program does it print stuff before 404?

Comment: Nooo I had just passed you again :(

Comment: @MDXF Haha sorry! I am having so much fun with this challenge

Comment: Brainbash for the last two (i'm at work, so I can't add any more languages right now. you guys are catching up fast)

Comment: @JoKing It isn't for me... Do you have a link where it does that? Your suggestion is shorter anyway, do you mind if I use it?

Comment: @dylnan haha me too (passed you again btw) :P

Comment: @JoKing [This](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLSizO@P@/oCgzr0TDxMBEk0vbUFlXN9pG204XBGJttPVAtJ42EOjZgUhrO2sb6w/zJ60BKgdRj@Yt/DB/xiQgbgDRj/pXAakVj/pXPuqbBVRyaDfIyIc7Zz9qmOP3cNfCw8sP7f7/HwA) is the second to last for brainbash and [this](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/@/oCgzr0TDxMBEk0vbUFlXN9pG204XBGJttPVAtJ42EOjZgUhrO2sb6w/zJ60BKgdRj@Yt/DB/xiQgbgDRj/pXAakVj/pXPuqbBVRyaHd8fDzI1Ic7Zz9qmOP3cNfCw8sP7f7/HwA) is the last for brainbash. They are both printing 404. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying

Comment: I see three boxes in the output. Maybe your browser isn't displaying the unprintable characters? (i'm on chrome) It prints hex bytes `9A 96 9A`, cell values 154, 150, 154

Comment: @JoKing I'm also on Chrome. Checked on my computer and phone and it works on both. Maybe a third person can check

Comment: @JoKing Weird that we aren't seeing the same thing. The program you gave prints 4041 for braingolf unfortunately

Comment: in the brainbash link I got [some weird chars and then 404](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e-kDICVOG7CxAmZB1feM1UmjK60twPec31yNIWCWWJs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can use `*` to destroy the atom in Fission if you need to

Comment: Fission works for the Cardinal addition. I think an R just snuck in there too early

Comment: @JoKing Oops, thanks. I think that happened when I was fixing Numberwang.

Answer (score 11):

## 11 languages, 10 bytes

#### Pyon

```
print(404
```

#### Pyon, Python 2

```
print 808//2
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1

```
print None or 404
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3

```
die=0
print(die or 404);
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3, Lua

```
print(None or 404)
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3, Lua, Perl 5

```
print(404 or 0)
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3, Lua, Perl 5, Ruby

```
;print("40"+"4")
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3, Lua, Perl 5, Ruby, Swift 4

```
print("40"+"4")
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3, Lua, Perl 5, Ruby, Swift 4, Perl 6

```
print(404**1)
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3, Lua, Perl 5, Ruby, Swift 4, Perl 6, Julia

```
print(404);
```

#### Pyon, Python 2, Python 1, Python 3, Lua, Perl 5, Ruby, Swift 4, Perl 6, Julia, Lily

```
print(404)
```

Comment: Nice. Very clean and simple answer and it still has plenty of languages

Answer (score 6):

## 4 Languages: CJam, Python, Underload, ><>

The following works in CJam but not Python, Underload, or ><>:

```
404
```

- To CJam: This pushes the literal `404` to the stack. The program ends, and the `404` is output.
- To Python: This program consists of a single expression `404`. The expression is evaluated, and the program terminates.
- To Underload: `4` and `0` are invalid commands, so the TIO interpreter simply ignores them, and the program terminates.
- To ><>: `404` pushes `4`, `0` and `4` to the stack. The IP wraps around to the beginning, and the program repeats infinitely.

---

The following works in CJam or Underload (though it errors) but not Python or ><>:

```
N(404)S;(\
```

- To CJam: `N` pushes a string (array of characters) containing a newline to the stack. `(` pops the single character (a newline) out of the string. `404` pushes `404` to the stack, and then `)` increments it to give `405`. `S;` pushes a spaces and then immediately deletes it. `(` decrements again to get `404`, and then `\` swaps the newline and the `404`. `404\n` is output (the empty array is displayed as nothing).
- To Underload: `N` is ignored. `(404)` pushes the string `404` to the stack. `S` outputs it. `;` is ignored. `(` causes the interpreter to try to look for a closing `)`, but as none is found, the program segfaults.
- To Python: This is invalid syntax (the expression `N(404)` is followed by an identifier `S`, which is malformed), so the program errors.
- To ><>: `N` is an invalid instruction, so the program errors.

---

The following works in CJam (though it errors), Underload, or Python, but not ><>:

```
[]
Le=404
+Le#(404)S
(print(404))
```

- To CJam: `[]` pushes the empty array to the stack, and `L` pushes the empty array to the stack. `e=` counts the number of occurrences of `[]` in `[]`, giving `0`. `404` pushes `404` to the stack. `+` adds the two numbers together, giving `404`. `L` pushes the empty array to the stack again, and `e#` creates a comment that lasts until the end of the line. `(` tries to pop an element out of an array, but since the top stack element is the empty array `[]`, the program errors. `404` is still output.
- To Python: `[]` is a statement consisting of a no-op instruction. `Le=404` defines a variable `Le` to be equal to `404`. `+Le` takes the unary plus of the variable `Le` (a rather useless operation) and the result is discarded. `#(404)S` is a line comment. `(print(404))` prints 404.
- To Underload: The only relevant part is `(404)S`, which pushes `404` to the stack and outputs it. `(print(404))` pushes `print(404)` to the stack, but nothing is done with it and the program terminates.
- To ><>: `[` tries to pop a number off the top stack on the metastack, and then pop that many elements off that stack and make them into a new stack which is then pushed to the metastack. There is no number on the stack, so the program errors.

---

The following works in CJam (though it errors), Python, Underload, and ><>:

```
"404nnn;\
"
Le=404
+Le#(404)S
(print(404))
```

- To CJam: Most of what I said last time applies here. Instead of being `[]`, we now have a string literal, but the content is still unimportant.
- To Python: Most of what I said last time applies here. Instead of being `[]`, the unused first expression is now a string literal, but the content is still unimportant.
- To Underload: Everything I said last time applies here. All of the commands are still ignored.
- To ><>: The `"` begins string mode, and the IP wraps around the first row pushing every character code it sees to the stack (this is unimportant). The IP wraps around and hits `"` again, which exits string mode. `404` pushes the digits `404` to the stack, and then `nnn` outputs each of them (technically, this happens in reverse order, but since 404 is a palindrome this doesn't matter). `;` ends the program.

Answer (score 6):

## 8 Languages, 498 Bytes

### BFFuck

```
outc(52)
outc(48)
outc(52)
```

### BFFuck, Python

```
print(404)
```

`print` prints a number in Python, while using  `print()` with a string without quotes it prints out the string in BFFuck.

### BFFuck, Python, Brainfuck

```
print(404)#+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+++.----.++++.
```

BFFuck and Python both support `#` as comments.

### BFFuck, Python, Brainfuck, Befunge-93

```
#["404",,,@]
print(404)#+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+++.----.++++.
```

### BFFuck, Python, Brainfuck, Befunge-93, PlusOrMinus

```
#["404",,,@]
print(404)#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-+++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+.-+++++.-
```

`-` in PlusOrMinus is the same as `.-` in BF, while `.` is an ignored character in PlusOrMinus

### BFFuck, Python, Brainfuck, Befunge-93, PlusOrMinus, Deadfish

```
#["404",,,@]iisoddddoiiso
print(404)#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-+++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+.-+++++.-
```

### BFFuck, Python, Brainfuck, Befunge-93, PlusOrMinus, Deadfish, Alphuck

```
#["404",,,@]pppiisoddddoiisosaeaeaepaepiceeeasccsajiiiijeeeej
print(404)#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-+++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+.-+++++.-s
```

The hardest, because it mixes up with Python and Deadfish.

### BFFuck, Python, Brainfuck, Befunge-93, PlusOrMinus, Deadfish, Alphuck, oOo CODE

```
#["404",,,@]pppiisoddddoiisosaeaeaepaepiceeeasccsajiiiijeeeej
print(404)#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-+++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#+.-+++++.-saazzzZzZzzzZzZzzzZzZzZzzzzZzZzZzZzzzzZZzZZzZZzZzzzzZZzzZzzZzZZzzzZZz
#ZzzZzzZzzZzzZZzZzZZzZZzZZzZZZz
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

## 6 Languages Brain-Hack, Brain-Flak, Brain-Fuck, Foo, Javascript, Alphuck

More to come!

### Brain-Hack

```
#(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})
```

Prints 404 in Brain-Hack

### Brain-Hack, Brain-Flak

```
(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})
```

### Brain-Hack, Brain-Flak, Brain-Fuck

```
(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})#-[<+>-----]<+.----.++++.>-.++++.
```

Uses comments in Brain-Flak to print it

### Brain-Hack, Brain-Flak, Brain-Fuck, Foo

```
"404"
(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})#-[<+>-----]<+.----.++++.>-.++++.
```

### Brain-Hack, Brain-Flak, Brain-Fuck, Foo, Javascript

```
console.log("404")
//(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})#-[<+>-----]<+.----.++++.>-.++++.
```

### Brain-Hack, Brain-Flak, Brain-Fuck, Foo, Javascript, Alphuck

```
console.log("404")
//(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})#-[<+>-----]<+.----.++++.>-.++++.iaipiiiiiaecsaejiiiijeeeej
```

Comment: Did i mention i use esolangs?

Comment: Umm, your original Brainfuck code prints `4`...

Comment: @MDXF fixed that lol

Comment: Now the brainfuck has alot of extra code.

Answer (score 3):

## 5 languages (87 bytes)

#### [Pyon](https://github.com/alexander-liao/pyon)

```
print(404
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMz/v/v6AoM69Ew8TA5P9/AA)

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/)

```python
print(404)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69Ew8TARPP/fwA)

#### [Brain-Flak (BrainHack)](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack)

```python
print(404)#(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/oCgzr0TDxMBEU1kDCDShGEgAoWZ1LRb0/z8A)

#### [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck)

Taken from [Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153724/59487) because I wasn't able to come up with a brainfuck code that had the brackets balanced (Brain-flak restriction).

```python
print(404)#(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})-[<+>-----]<+.----.++++.>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v@/oCgzr0TDxMBEU1kDCDShGEgAoWZ1LRakG22jbacLArE22nogWk8bCPTs/v8HAA)

#### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)

Note that this also works with Ohm.

```python
#404q
print(404)#(((()((()(((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){}){})-[<+>-----]<+.----.++++.>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f2cTApJCroCgzr0QDyNRU1gACTSgGEkCoWV2LBelG22jb6YJArI22HojW0wYCPbv//wE)

Thanks to Jo King for -6 bytes.

Comment: The `x%x` and `[-]` aren’t necessary

Comment: @JoKing Oh whoops I forgot to remove them after adapting your brainfuck code >_<. Edited. Thanks

Comment: You can easily add Python 1: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77ed24162c35aae0a10e4e1cada8547a

Comment: @MDXF That seems invalid to me. 1) The Python 1 version doesn’t work in Pyon 2) The Python 1 version also works in Python 2, which is forbidden.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh, I forgot that the non-parenthesis syntax works in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

## 2 Languages, 24 bytes, Python and Batch

## Program 1: Python 3

```
print('404')
```

## Program 2: Python 3 and Batch

```
print('404')#|echo 404
```

After the the hash comments the rest of the code in python, and the | is a statement in bash to do this if the other command fails.

Answer (score 0):

## 2 Languages, 53 bytes: C and Python

Let's start things off with something simple.

### Program 1: C

```
int main(){printf("404");}
```

### Program 2: C and Python

```
#define print(X)int main(){printf("404");}
print(404)
```

TIO links:

- [C program 1](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzT0OzuqAIyEnTUDIxMFHStK79/x8A)
- [Python program 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/XzklNS0zL1WhoCgzr0QjQhNIKuQmZuZpaFaDhdI0lEwMTJQ0rWu5IEqAPM3//wE)

This is just an example, and will probably be beaten **many** times over.

Answer (score 0):

## 4 languages, 91 bytes

## C++

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){printf("%d",404);}
#endif
```

## C++, C

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){printf("%d",404);}
```

Removes the C++ macro

## C++, C, Befunge

```
#define A "404",,,@
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){printf("%d",404);}
```

Adds a macro that will be ignored in C++, but read as code in Befunge.

## C++, C, Befunge, Python

```
#define A "404",,,@
#include "stdio.h"//\
print(404);'''
int main(){printf("%d",404);}//'''
```

Ads a piece of code that causes the next line to be a comment in C, but not in Python (`//<backslash>`)